# display text on screen along with audio player in ios

Tags: ios, audio

How to display text along with audio player? Like audio is playing by audio player, & corresponding text or lyrics is displaying on the screen.

Comment: you have to find audio file meta data.... check on google that how we can get meta data of an audio file

Answer (score 1):

Check this

```
NSURL* songURL = [mediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL] 
AVAsset* songAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:songURL options:nil]; 
NSString* lyrics = [songAsset lyrics];
```